# How do I extract my YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

I have uploaded quite a few videos to YouTube. I'd like to download them all and move them to a different video sharing service. I don't necessarily have the original final files that I uploaded, so I'd like to get them out in the same format I uploaded them in. (Don't want to have to re-edit.)

How can I get my own videos from YouTube?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/). They have added the option to download your YouTube videos.

> With Google Takeout, you can download all of the ***original*** videos that you have uploaded in a few simple clicks.  No transcoding or transformation -- you’ll get exactly the same videos that you first uploaded.  Your videos in.  Your videos out.

[Source](http://dataliberation.blogspot.com/2012/09/your-youtube-original-videos-now.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your have "video manager" when you are logged into YT > http://www.youtube.com/my_videos?feature=mhee

Every video has "Download MP4" option.

Comment: Not all of the videos I uploaded were in MP4 format. I want them back in the same format I submitted them.